# Well supported Hardware Raid Controller

Tags: hardware, raid

I am currently planning to buy a hardware-raid controller. This became necessary since I am running Linux and Windows in parallel and now need the redundancy for both OS (Im am going to use RAID1 / Mirroring).

Therefore I am searching for a hardware raid controller which is well supported by linux / ubuntu (reporting smart values, stats for the harddrives, etc...). This controller should have four sata ports and if possible it should fit in a PCIE-1x Slot.

I would greatly appreciate, if you could suggest some devices.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look at following:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog

Edit:

Following raid cards are certified:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/RAID

Comment: My personal experience is that the Dell PERC card is awesome :-)

Comment: Both links are dead/404.

Answer (score 1):

Get a good LSI controller and move on. Great SATA and SAS support so now you have an upgrade path when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you find a product and then find out if it works in Linux. I say this because Linux support of these sorts of devices is usually very good because they're commonly used in enterprise situations on Linux servers.

Pricing and hardware features are going to be your real delimiters here.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of asus motherboards use nvidia raid controllers. i happen to have one and it works very well on my ubuntu-server box with 1 raid1 and 1 raid0.