# Ubuntu on HP Server

Tags: server

I would like to ask about HP DL320 with software RAID configuration, is there any HP mode which supports RAID 1 and RAID5 with Ubuntu?

On HP DL360 instead, does it's support RAID1 and RAID5?
Could you guys advice me is there any different HP server model which supports RAID 1 and RAID5 on ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I think theme is discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26695/well-supported-hardware-raid-controller)

[Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/category/RAID/) is list of supported components for RAID